# Nodemcu reboot infinitly

Tags: message, nodemcu

When I upload code to my nodemcu and open the port I get a set of messages which repeat automatically and infinitely. 
Does anyone have idea how to solve this problem?

```
stdin:1: '=' expected near 'number'
> lua: cannot open init.lua
> ��

Nstdststdin:1: function arguments expected near 'open'
> distdin:1: function arguments expected near 'open'
> n:1: function arguments expected stdin:1: unfinished string near ''>        ERROR'
```

> near 'open'
>   instdin:1: function arguments expected near 'open'
>   :1: function arguments expected near 'open'
>   odeMstdin:1: function arguments expecte

Comment: You'll want to re-flash the firmware and then consider http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/upload/#initlua.

Comment: @MarcelStör is right, the reboot is due to a syntactical error.

Comment: You can also invoke format() from ESPlorer if you're quick enough. That way, you can get around the need for flashing. Happens to me all the time.